# React Hook Form | onBlur logic based on validation error

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I need to add some logic on field blur, regarding the field's validation error.

My problem is that the event `onBlur` of the field is happening before `errors` object is updated.

How can I have updated `errors` object while `onBlur` logic on specific field is fired.

**EDIT:**

it's a structure form component.
partial code:

```
const Form = {fields} => {
        const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control, setValue, trigger } = useForm({
                mode: 'onBlur'
            });
        const getErrorMessage = field => {
            const fieldError = errors[field.name];
            switch (fieldError.type) {
            case 'required':
            return 'field is mandatory';
            case 'minLength': 
            return 'min length error';
            }
        }
        
        const formElements = fields.map((field, index) => {
            const error = getErrorMessage(field);
            switch (field.element) {
                        case 'textfield':
                            return <Input {...attribs} onBlurCallback={field.onBlur}/>
                            break;
                        case 'checkbox':
                            return <Checkbox {...attribs} onBlurCallback={field.onBlur} checked={field.checked} />
                            break;
            }
        }
        
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {formElements}
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Add some code so we can have context of what your are saying

Comment: @sasal added, thanks